# incorrect processing of the function moving text file components

Tags: c, file, pointers

I was trying to write a function to cyclically shift the components of a file (integers) in such a way if they were written to an array. In case of single iteration the function works correctly, but in case of multiple iterations the values start to be written to the file incorrectly. The number of offset iterations n must not exceed the number of file components. The number of components is unlimited Additional files and arrays cannot be used, the components of the file must be accessed directly (fseek()).

```
void shiftElements(FILE* file, int numsCount, int lastElementPosition, int n) {
    int temp;
    int buffer;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        fseek(file, (numsCount-i-1) * sizeof(int), 0);
        fscanf_s(file, "%d", &temp);
        printf("\n%d\n", temp);

        for (int j = numsCount - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            fseek(file, (j - 1) * sizeof(int), 0);
            fscanf_s(file, "%d", &buffer);
            printf("\n----%d\n", buffer);

            if (buffer < 10) {
                fseek(file, j * sizeof(int), 0);
                fprintf(file, "%d ", buffer);
            }
            else {
                fseek(file, j * sizeof(int), 0);
                fprintf(file, "%d", buffer);
            }
        }

        fseek(file, 0, 0);
        fprintf(file, "%d ", temp);
    }
}
    

void executionForSecondBlock(FILE* file_block_2, int numsCount, int n) {
    int lastElementPosition;
    int c;

    for (int i = 0; i < numsCount; i++) {
        c = rand() % 100;
        fseek(file_block_2, i * sizeof(int), 0);
        fprintf(file_block_2, "%d", c);
        if (i == numsCount - 2) {
            lastElementPosition = ftell(file_block_2);
        }
    }

    int pointerPosition = ftell(file_block_2);
    printf("\tЗапис закiнчився на %d позицiї покажчика\n", pointerPosition);

    printf("\n\tВиведення з файлу пiсля запису: \n");
    fseek(file_block_2, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < numsCount; i++) {
        fseek(file_block_2, i * sizeof(int), 0);
        fscanf_s(file_block_2, "%d", &c);
        printf("\t%d", c);
    }

    fseek(file_block_2, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        shiftElements(file_block_2, numsCount, n);
    }

    printf("\n\n\tВиведення з файлу пiсля змiщення: \n");
    fseek(file_block_2, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < numsCount; i++) {
        fseek(file_block_2, i * sizeof(int), 0);
        fscanf_s(file_block_2, "%d", &c);
        printf("\t%d", c);
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me what the problem is and cow can I fix it?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: When you write to a text-file, the text you write have to be the *exact same length* as the one you replace. Otherwise you will just overwrite text you don't want to overwrite. There's no way to automatically "shift" contents of a file, only overwrite what is in the file to begin with. That's why it's recommended to use a temporary storage, for the old *or* the new contents, and write out the new modified contents after truncating the contents of the original file.

Comment: You can only safely do this kind of thing directly with fixed-length fields in the file.

Comment: Is this a binary file or a text file? Using `sizeof(int)` in your `fseek` suggests binary, but reading with `%d` only works with text.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the new data will be written over the old data, overwriting it. I tried to implement this mechanism in a function, but something goes wrong. Could you help me with debugging?

Comment: As pointed out: 1) If file content uses text representations, sizeof(int) is wrong and you must enforce fixed width fields, which you don't. 2) If file content uses binary representations, fprintf/fscanf with %d is wrong. Consider using fwrite/fread in this case instead. 3) File open access mode of binary or not could be an issue in some cases for some platforms (Windows).

Comment: It is not the source of your issue, but do not use `fscanf_s` or the other `*_s` functions unless someone is forcing you to do.  Although they are somewhat portable in principle, they are non-portable in practice, and the extra security they claim to afford is mostly illusory.  Here, your particular usage of `fscanf_s` doesn't afford even a *claimed* security benefit over `fscanf`.